# How to find the number of users using an app simultaneously per day/hour from the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe with the columns

```
start_time 
end_time 
user
app
```

How can i find the number of simultaneous users per app, per day/hour.

I want to display something like:

```
No. of simultaneous users per {app} per {day} : N
No. of simultaneous users per {app} per {hour of the above day} : a fraction of N
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can use an f string of sorts

```
f"blah blah blah {app} foo {day} : N"
```

Is this what you are looking for?